# The footer is too small

Tags: feature-request, design, footer

I just dealt with [another case](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/87618/2) with SE license confusion (look at the bottom, it says the contribution is public domain, even though it is not.)

This kind of confusion can be often caused by the small size of the legal footer:

> <sub><sup>site design / logo © {CurrentYear} Stack Exchange Inc; user contributions licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) with [attribution required](//blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required)</sup></sub>

If you cannot see it, here is a bigger version (more similar to the real footer):

> <sub>site design / logo © {CurrentYear} Stack Exchange Inc; user contributions licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) with [attribution required](//blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required)</sub>

And an even bigger one (+1 if you were unable to see the other two):

> site design / logo © {CurrentYear} Stack Exchange Inc; user contributions licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) with [attribution required](//blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required)

(okay, stop here)

Because this can be a real problem, especially for those with visual problems, I request for the footer to be enlarged. For some sites, low contrast is also a problem.

## Specifically, I request a footer that can be easily read by all.

Comment: Why do you think that making the footer larger would make more people read it?

Comment: @Oded Some people just can't read it.

Comment: My point is - it is the footer. **Most** people don't bother reading it.

Comment: @Oded Again, there are the ones who do. Why should Stack Exchange be built for "most" people and not for "all" people? Oh, I am not one of the "most" people by the way.

Comment: ctrl-scrollwheel-up

Answer (score 2):

The footer is just a quick notice, and it is not so important. They could remove it and I am not even against that.

If you want to know how the content is licensed, just click the *legal* link in the footer. If the footer would be enlarged a lot, it would be very distracting for most users, who aren't even interested in it. Just keep it as is.

(I'm not sure, but maybe it is just there to comply to the CC-by-SA license. If so, that could be the only reason the footer is there...)

Comment: [I'm against your opinion.](/q/283017/283018#comment917367_283017) If it complies, it should be readable by everyone. Also, I see *no reference* to CC BY-SA 3.0 there! I even used a Find tool. Just put the screen 80 inches from your head and try to read the footer. You can barely read it at all. That's similar to how visually impaired people see.

Comment: You can't build the site for everyone. Some like blue, some hate it. SE decides which information is deemed to be useful and what not. Giving the font, the footer is less important.